# How to use the dot short form for class when class name has hyphens?

Tags: pug, template-engine, pugjs

The following:

```
span.M
```

generates nicely into:

```
<span class='M'>
```

However,

```
span.glyphicon glyphicon-book
```

does not work.

Is that a way to save typing and shifting for class names similar to the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pug engine does [render code blocks](https://runkit.com/58c101dc2329e30014539c37/58c101dc2329e30014539c38) of the type:

```
span.glyphicon-glyphicon-book
```

However, I think when you say *not working*, you mean that the glyphicon is not being replace. For that, you need to have two different classes like so:

```
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-book
```

Answer (score 1):

This class will be rendered successfully but it's wrong, it should be like this:

```
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-book
```

Because you need a glyphicon class and a glyphicon-book class for it to display properly.